# How to set the ID of a new entity in Datastore using the web console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google Cloud Platform's Firestore in Datastore mode.

I'm trying to use GCP's web console to add an entity with `id=123`. When I click the **Create an Entity** link, I get the following options:

[image]

Now what am I supposed to do? If I select the first option, it auto-generates a random integer which is definitely not 123. If I chose Custom Name, it lets me set the value to 123, but the field is not `id`, it is `name`. What's the solution?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's called `name` or `id` since it doesn't affect in any way getting the data of it. Is there any requirement that forces the entity identifier to be called `id`?

Comment: Not currently possible via the UI (only possible programmatically - see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#specifying_your_own_key_name).

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki to help other community members that may encounter this issue.

As stated by @NoCommandLine:
This is currently not possible via the UI. However, you can do it programmatically.

---

For more information, you may check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#specifying_your_own_key_name).